# Error "pq: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block" running on Golang and Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, go

My code Repository Create Product

```
func (r *RepoProduct) CreateProductData(data *models.Products) (string, error) {
    tx := r.MustBegin()
    var new_id string
    tx.Get(&new_id, "select gen_random_uuid()")
    data.Id_product = new_id
    _, err := tx.NamedExec(`INSERT INTO golang.products (id_product, id_category, banner_product, product_title, price, favorite) VALUES(:id_product, :id_category, :banner_product, :product_title, :price, :favorite) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, data)
    if err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return "", err
    }

    tx.Commit()

    return "add product data successful", nil
}
```

and, my code handler Create Product

```
func (h *ProductHandler) CreateProduct(ctx *gin.Context) {
    var productset models.Products

    if err := ctx.ShouldBind(&productset); err != nil {
        // ctx.AbortWithError(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "status":      http.StatusBadRequest,
            "description": "Bad Requestt",
            "message":     err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    productset.Banner_product = ctx.MustGet("banner_product").(string)
    response, err := h.CreateProductData(&productset)
    if err != nil {
        // ctx.AbortWithError(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "status":      http.StatusBadRequest,
            "description": "Bad Request",
            "message":     err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }
    ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "status":      http.StatusOK,
        "description": "OK",
        "message":     response,
    })
}
```

When I run on postman to post data, the data is rejected and there is an error "pq: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block"

Comment: This error occurs when you attempt to use a transaction but a [previous query has failed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/303937). To assist you with this we would need the database code (i.e. `MustBegin()` etc). Ideally make a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (the http handler is really irrelevant). I'd suggest checking all errors (there is a good chance something that you assume will always succeed is, in fact, failing).

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend few optimizations to the repository code:

1. call `defer tx.Rollback` right after creating a transaction
2. you do not need to get the random UUID, if you configure your table to use the same call as a default value, i.e. `ALTER TABLE golang.products CHANGE COLUMN id_product UUID DEFAULT gen_random_uuid()`
3. the string return value seems as a logging artifact that should be only carried within your handler, the repository should only return values from DB and/or errors

The final repository code could then look like this:

```
func (r *RepoProduct) CreateProductData(data *models.Products) error {
    tx := r.MustBegin()

    defer tx.Rollback() // will be called whenever your function returns

    if _, err := tx.NamedExec(`INSERT INTO golang.products (id_category, banner_product, product_title, price, favorite)
VALUES (:id_category, :banner_product, :product_title, :price, :favorite)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, data); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    tx.Commit() // without defer tx.Rollback(), if tx.Commit() fails, you end up with (b)locked transaction
    // additionally, to cover existing code bug enclose the tx.Commit()
    // within proper error handling, replace the previous line with this:
    /*
    if err = tx.Commit(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    */
    // this way the handler is notified about a failure when trying to commit to the DB

    // however, if you move the gen_random_uuid() to the table definition 
    // and do not get the value from the DB before inserting the data,
    // there's even no need for transactions here

    return nil
}
```